# Strange behaviour with WAMP and an Ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wampserver

I'm currently trying to run a script which works on my LAMP environment but not on a WAMP environment:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: '<?php echo ROOT_DIR;?>/member/login-process',
            type: "post",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data == 'success')
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '<?php echo ROOT_DIR;?>/dashboard';}, 2000);
                }

                else
                {
                    $("#alert").html('<div class="alert alert-error"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> '+data+'</div>');
                }
            }
        });
```

When I try it on LAMP, it works fine: i'm redirected. With WAMP, I don't know why, but I have the following error message (generated by the "else"):

> success

I've tried typeof(data) and I have "string" as result. The value returned by the Ajax query is therefore the "success" string, so why the "if" is ignored?

Comment: What is ROOT_DIR equal to?

Comment: It's equal to http://localhost/myproject. It's not a problem for this bug.

Comment: Could it be "success " returned? Try that: `if ($.trim(data) === 'success')`

Comment: @A. Wolff Dude, you'r a migician, it works. why I have this behaviour only with WAMP and not LAMP?

Comment: I'm quite sure both files on each server are not exactly the same. If they are, post the relevant php code (used on WAMP) so we can see what's going on

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gaetanm/3724093d0b5d0e197521

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var go = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo ROOT_DIR;?>/member/login-process',
    data: $('form').serialize()
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.debug("DATA:");
    console.debug(data);
    if (data == 'success')
    {
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '<?php echo ROOT_DIR;?>/dashboard';}, 2000);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#alert").html('<div class="alert alert-error"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> '+data+'</div>');
    }
})
.fail(function(msg) {
    alert('Error: ' + msg);
})
.always(function() {
});
```

`success` has been the traditional name of the success callback in jQuery, defined as an option in the ajax call. However, since the implementation of `$.Deferred` and more sophisticated callbacks, `done` is the preferred way to implement success callbacks, as it can be called on any deferred.

Comment: Thanks for this detailled answer, but it doesn't work, still the same problem.

Comment: Then it is most likely something in your PHP or Apache configuration as it is host specific.